# wordpress if is page

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom WordPress theme on which I display different backgrounds for different pages.

E.g.

```
    <body <?php body_class(); ?>>
    <?php if (is_page('about')) : ?>
        <body style="background:url(background-stripe.gif); background-repeat: no-repeat;">
    <?php endif; ?>
```

I am currently trying to get this applied to a custom post type (single) page as well , what is the best method to have that achieved?

Comment: Okay I got this to work using if (is_single

Comment: Here is a topic of your question in wordpress question page http://wordpress.org/support/topic/change-background-image-per-page-1

Answer (score 1):

Instead of these conditions I'd use the [body_class()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class) function on the `body` tag. It adds classes for custom types which should suffice, but if you need more you can add a class with a filter in your page template. Then you only have to set the background in the CSS file with `body.custom-page` or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

[is_singular](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_singular) is the conditional tag for specific post types. You could use that if you don't want different backgrounds for all single posts/different post types.

Having said that, I would use body_class as already suggested.